# How to compare values in one column

Tags: r, shiny

I have a problem with my shiny app: I have a data table of this form:

1. 125
2. 165
3. 598
4. 687
5. etc

And I would like to compare the values ​​so that if they are identical I know it.

i try:

```
complete2 <- reactive({
 dt2 <- MY.DATA.TABLE
 i <- 1
 for (i in 1:(length(dt2$n)-2)){
   if (dt2[dt2$n,i] == dt2[dt2$n,i+1]){
     i = i +1
     p <- 1
   } 
   else {
     i = i +1
     p <- 0
   }
 }
 return(p)
})
```

Comment: You may use `duplicated(df1$col)`  If it is to check adjacent element, use `rle(df1$col)`

Comment: and how use duplicated? i don't understand...

Comment: Try `v1 <- c(1, 2, 2, 5, 6, 6); +(c(FALSE, v1[-1] == v1[-length(v1)]))`

Comment: don't work... don't understand

Comment: ok, if the intention is to create a flag based on the duplicate elements

Comment: I would like to check that all the values ​​are identical

Comment: ok, so in your column `125 165 598 687`, which one is identical

Comment: in this example, no one. But how can i know?

Comment: The expected output is  not clear.  Try `duplicated(df1$col1)|duplicated(df1$col1, fromLast = TRUE)` or  just `duplicated(df1$col1)`

Comment: the output can be 1/0 or TRUE/FALSE or ... i just need to know is all the values are identical.

Comment: Then the duplicated willl return `TRUE/FALSE` as welll

Comment: When you say that all value are identical.  Is it like `121 121 121` returns TRUE and `122 121 122` returns FALSE?  If that is the case `all(df1$col1 == df1$col1[1])` or `setequal(df1$col1, df1$col1[1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can wrap with `all` to check if all the values are identical by comparing the column with one of the elements, say first element.  It returns a single TRUE/FALSE output

```
all(df1$col1 == df1$col1[1])
```

Or with `setequal`

```
setequal(df1$col1, df1$col1[1])
```